# converting string mathematical instruction into its equivalent operation

Tags: python, string, dictionary, string-matching

i want to convert a string mathematical instruction into it's equivalent integer operation;

eg:
1.'double three'= 33

2. 'triple six'=666

my code is:

```
hashmap={
'one': '1',
'two': '2',
'three': '3',
'four': '4',
'five': '5',
'six': '6',
'seven': '7',
'eight': '8',
'nine': '9',
'zero' : '0'}


str1="one five three"
st2int = ''.join(hashmap[ele] for ele in str1.split())
print(st2int)
```

my program is only for the `str` numbers to integer..
how can i make it to work for instruction like `double,triple,quadraple`etc  as i mentioned in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a separate dict for multipliers and for digits. If a word is in the multipliers dictionary, remember what its multiplier value is. If it's in the digits dictionary, multiply by the current multiplier.

```
multipliers = {
    'double': 2,
    'triple': 3,
    'quadruple': 4
}
digits = {
    'one': '1',
    'two': '2',
    'three': '3',
    'four': '4',
    'five': '5',
    'six': '6',
    'seven': '7',
    'eight': '8',
    'nine': '9',
    'zero' : '0'
}

inputs = [ "one five three", "triple six", "double two", "triple double nine" ]
for i in inputs:
    multiplier = 1
    numbers = []
    for word in i.split():
        if word in multipliers:
            multiplier = multiplier * multipliers[word]
        if word in digits:
            numbers.append(multiplier * digits[word])
            multiplier = 1
    print(''.join(numbers))
```

This prints:

```
153
666
22
999999
```